# SharePoint 2013 newsfeed MUI dates formatting error

Tags: 2013, mysite, newsfeed, language-pack, mui

We are having a very strange issue with SharePoint 2013 newsfeed. The user has reported that dates in news feed posts are mixing languages in the my site host root page. In our environment we have 15 different languages and each user must see all dates formatted correctly by his regional configurations and of course we can't change the regional configuration of the my site host site collection.

After same tests we figured out that day and month names are using my site host regional settings and are formatted by user language preference. All other text in the page is showing user preferred language as you can see in the attached image.

[image: English regional configration in my site host but Spanish user]
[image: English regional configuration in my site host but Russian user]

We need to know if this is a product limitations or we are doing something wrong.
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution: users must have selected the "Always use my personal settings" in his profile configuration.

[image: Enable Allways use my personal settings in user profile]